# What Open Ports are Necessary for SQL Server Log Shipping to Secondary on the Internet

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

Our secondary server will be on the other end of an always on IPSEC tunnel. We need to instruct our customer's firewall/VPN/Server team (they are responsible for the primary).

What I've gathered so far, is that I need for the log files to be copied to the secondary, I need CIFS ports opened:

ports 135,137,138,139,445

Per this question, I need to also make sure the SQL Server is NOT set to dynamic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540007/1192939

and it seems, all that's required beyond that would be for 1433 to be available:

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sql-server-tcp-and-udp-ports

Am I leaving out anything?

Comment: UDP 1434 probably should be open to allow name browsing.